# Swift Thai Localization Problems

Tags: swift, localization

There seems to be a problem with the String library that apple uses.

Here's my `Localizable.strings`

```
"error_failed_to_retrieve_certificate" = "เกิิดผิดพลาดในการกู้คะแนน";
```

Here's how I set it to any view

```
anyView.text = return NSLocalizedString("error_failed_to_retrieve_certificate", comment: "")
```

But somehow the string that is being displayed gets warped, when it gets displayed, (the second character becomes different.

Here's what it looks like too when I search it using the Project Search.

[image]
[image]

But on the Strings it looks different (notice the third character)

[image]

Here's one image that is side by side

[image]

Comment: show your localize file screenShot

Comment: ya its the issue I also checked

Comment: but once try in your UI wherever you gonna show it coz in output it is showing correctly

Comment: My output is showing the one with the weird circle thingy.

Comment: @AbecedarioPoint the screenshots there are my localized file screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I don't know any Thai.

It seems like that your string has an extra  ิ (U+0E34 THAI CHARACTER SARA I) in it. The character before that, กิ, is already two code points combined - ก (U+0E01 THAI CHARACTER KO KAI) and  ิ, so the extra  ิ got displayed alone. I would say it's an Xcode bug.

I've removed the extra character here:

```
เกิดผิดพลาดในการกู้คะแนน
```

Copy and paste that and it should be fine.

Comment: I will try this, if it fixes the problem I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: @ZonilyJame Did it work? What problems (if any) are you having?

Comment: Hi @Sweeper it did work. Thank you, I'll just have to scan through the rest of the strings to see if there are any more extra characters added in my strings, it really does seem to be an xcode/ios issue. I'll have to send a bug report to apple about this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you have unique key "error_failed_to_retrieve_certificate". this key value is unique.